# Multiply two arrays to get matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy arrays

```py
#shape = (5,)
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

#shape = (3,)
b = np.array([6,7,8])
```

I want to get a matrix from this arrays like this:

```py
#shape = (3,5)
c = [
    [1*6, 2*6, 3*6, 4*6, 5*6],
    [1*7, 2*7, 3*7, 4*7, 5*7],
    [1*8, 2*8, 3*8, 4*8, 5*8]
]
```

Is there a way to do this using numpy functions?

Comment: `a * b[:, None]`

Comment: or [`np.outer(b, a)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```py
>>> a*b.reshape(3,1)
array([[ 6, 12, 18, 24, 30],
       [ 7, 14, 21, 28, 35],
       [ 8, 16, 24, 32, 40]])
```

By reshaping `b`, we are transforming it as follows:

```
>>> b.reshape(3,1)
array([[6],
       [7],
       [8]])
```

Since this is a 2d-array, whose second dimension is 1, numpy is able to multiply it by `a` on the left by [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/theory.broadcasting.html) `b`. It will be as if the multiplication was actually

```py
>>> np.array([1,2,3,4,5])*np.array([[6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
...                                 [7, 7, 7, 7, 7],
...                                 [8, 8, 8, 8, 8]])
array([[ 6, 12, 18, 24, 30],
       [ 7, 14, 21, 28, 35],
       [ 8, 16, 24, 32, 40]])
```

Comment: Suggest adding a brief comment about broadcasting. If someone doesn't know [numpy broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) this might be hard to understand.