# elementwise operation actually performs matrix operation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say you have two (or more) `numpy` `ndarrays` of equal `size` (meaning they have equal number of elements) like:

```
A = np.array([[1],[2],[3]]) #Define a 3-element column vector
B = np.array([1,2,3]) #Define a 3-element row vector
```

Given that numpy's documentation advertises the `*` and `/` operators as "elementwise" between two `ndarray` types why do the following:

```
AtimesB = A*B
AoverB = A/B
```

return:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 4, 6],
       [3, 6, 9]]) #AtimesB
array([[1.        , 0.5       , 0.33333333],
       [2.        , 1.        , 0.66666667],
       [3.        , 1.5       , 1.        ]]) #AoverB
```

instead of:

```
array([1,4,9])
array([1,1,1])
```

To my knowledge, it is the `@` operator which is meant to do matrix multiplications and `np.divide` handles the matrix divisions. What am I missing here? Is this the way `numpy` handles ambiguity regarding array `shapes`?

Comment: numpy doesn't have the concept of row (column) vector. A 1d array represents both row and column vectors in linear algebra. In your case, your "column vector" is 2d and "row vector" is 1d. `*` and `/` give matrix operations due to [numpy broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

Comment: I think the technical term for this operation is the 'outer product' of the two vectors.  It can also be done with [`np.outer`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html). Someone actually explained how broadcasting works yesterday in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68059457/1609514).

Comment: `shape` gives more information than `size`.  There's more to `element-wise` operations than just the number of elements.  One array is (3,1) shape, the other (3,).  For broadcasting purposes that (3,) is equivalent to (1,3).  Together you get a (3,3), an 'outer' operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`np.divide`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.divide.html) actually is for element wise division. The element wise operations using * or / are only done if the arrays are of equal shape (and not size). Otherwise the arrays are [broadcasted](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html#broadcasting) if possible.
In order to guarantee element wise multiplication, you can use [`np.multiply`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html#numpy.multiply).

Answer (score 2):

`A` must be a row too to get the result you expect!

```
>>> A
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])
>>> A.T
array([[1, 2, 3]])
>>> A.T * B
array([[1, 4, 9]])
>>> A.T / B
array([[1., 1., 1.]])
```